# sql server EXPRESS instance with windows authentication does not have any permissions to create a db

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express

sql server EXPRESS instance with windows authentication does not have any permissions to create a db.

i have installed VS 2008. so i got SQLEXpress installed. and then separately i installed management studio 2008.

When i connect to the instance using windows  login, it connected. but It does not have permissions to create any db or create any login.

How can i fix this permissions issue. My windows authentication does not have any permissions to do anything on my sqlexpress db.

can any one help on this..

errro: access denied. no permission..

thank you

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem.
When I completely reinstalled SQL Server 2008 Express and Management Studio the problem was missing.
Also when you install the SQL Server you can add password for 'sa' user.